# What is SIGBABY?

Tags: php, linux, signals, posix

Occasionally I see this signal implemented in frameworks, platforms and languages. But Google doesn't give anything about it.

I'd like to know its common uses, history and/or what it originally meant for.

Comment: What are the frameworks, platforms and languages?

Comment: It's only PHP I am using, and I came across some C libraries from Google earlier. Must be a joke I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It must be joke by Derick Rethans. He added [SIGBABY to PHP](http://marc.info/?l=php-cvs&m=100289252314474&w=2) as an alias of SIGSYS, or signal 31. As far as I can tell, it does not exist anywhere else.

Comment: Note: It is defined in the [PCNTL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) [extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.constants.php). It is an extension for creating/controlling UNIX-style processes.

Comment: In Linux, signal 31 is `SIGSYS`, or "bad system call". I wonder how exactly it can be used in PHP then?

Comment: AFAIK if you give a signal handler it doesn't care, just in case I missed that somewhere and then something smash in my face.

Answer (score 12):

I've only just now noticed this question, after somebody asked about it on Twitter.

`SIGBABY` is indeed in an inside joke. Back in 2001, we discussed most PHP related things on the #php.pecl channel on IRC. Wez Furlong's kid had just been born, and Wez would often sign off for a bit with "SIGBABY" - as in indication that he needed some family time with the little one. As this happened so much, I added [SIGBABY](http://marc.info/?l=php-cvs&m=100289252314474&w=2) to pcntl. I had no idea it was still in there though!

Comment: Wow, Wez’s baby should be old enough to enjoy this story!

Comment: This is amazing. That baby is almost old enough to drink.